# Spotify Android SDK authorization only works if Spotify app is active

Tags: android, kotlin, spotify

I'm trying to integrate the Spotify SDK into my Kotlin application, for which I'm following Spotify's [Getting started](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/tutorials/getting-started) guide. I'm using the "built-in auth flow" just like in their tutorial, this is my code:

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val connectionParams = ConnectionParams.Builder(client_id)
            .setRedirectUri(resources.getString(redirect_uri))
            .showAuthView(true)
            .build()

        SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams,
            object : Connector.ConnectionListener {
                override fun onConnected(appRemote: SpotifyAppRemote) {
                    spotifyAppRemote = appRemote
                    Log.d("Spotify", "Connected! Yay!")
                }

                override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("Spotify", "Failed to connect to Spotify: $throwable")
                }
            }
        )
```

The problem is that this authorization only works if the Spotify app was active (in the foreground? sry, i don't know the correct android terminology) right before I start my own app. If I start my app and the Spotify app is **not** active, then the authorization does not work. The auth view dialog (where the user would log in) does not pop up, neither `onConnected` nor `onFailure` are called.

If I had to guess, I'd say that it fails to show the auth view dialog itself, but I'm not sure how to approach this issue.

Edit: I'm using Android 14

Answer (score 0):

you want to initialize the SDK at your application level it seems you are calling SpotifyAppRemote.connect() on activity or fragment

you want to initialize in your class that implements: Application i.e

```
BaseApplication: Application{
  SpotifyAppRemote.connect()
}
```

the lifecycle of the: Application is alive as long as the app is still in the background and not forced killed

Comment: I'm initializing SpotifyAppRemote in the `onStart` method of my main activity. This is how its done in Spotify's guide, too.